# how can I change numbers from 10 radix to 2 in C language in Code :: blocks IDE?

Tags: c

I wrote this code to change the radix of numbers from 10 to 2, but it does not work well. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
//changing numbers from 10 radix to 2.
int main()
{
int n ,i=0 , s=0 ;
printf("Please Enter a number in ten radix: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
while(n!=0){
    int r=n%2 ;
    s= s+(r*(10^i));
    i++;
    int m=n/2;
    n=m;
}
printf("\nThe number in two radix is %d",s);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can simply form a string..why represent in a decimal?

Comment: I do not what a string is. because I am an amateur programmer.

Comment: You can simply store the resulted bits into characters and store them in char array.

Comment: The  [`^` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) does not what you think it does.

Comment: thanks everybody, the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
int n, r = 0, i, base2[50];
printf("Please Enter a number in ten radix: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
while(n!=0){
    base2[r]=n%2 ;
    r++;
    n = n/2;
}
printf("\nThe number in two radix is);
for(i = r; i >= 0; i--)
{
   printf("%d", base2[i]);
}
return 0;

}
```